# How can I pull a contextual link into a Page Layout

Tags: page-layout, xslt, url

We are creating a new commerce site for our existing SharePoint 2010 site to link to. Right now our main product pages each use layouts that have an unordered list styled into tabs across the top. The links are relative (../pages/ordering.aspx is where our current ordering information resides, for example).

I now need to change the ordering page links to go to our new commerce site. I would like a specific product ordering link to go to a specific page on the new commerce site.

I was hoping I could create a list that had the sharepoint link in one column and the corresponding commerce link in another column, but I don't know how to code it. Any ideas?

Here is what the ordering tabs look like:
[image: tabs]

Here is the Page Layout code for the tabs:

```
<ul id="OMSOD_Tabs">
<li class="tab1 ActiveTab">
<a href="../pages/Overview.aspx">Product Overview</a></li>
<li class="tab2">
<a href="../pages/Specifications.aspx">Technical Specifications</a></li>
<li class="tab3">
<a href="../pages/Ordering.aspx">ORDER Now!</a></li>
<li class="tab4">
<a href="../pages/Downloads.aspx">Downloads</a></li>
```

I want to replace the url for the ORDER Now! tab with the contextual link based on the current page url.

Thanks!